# vk авторизация от имени сообщества

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vknet

Начинаю программировать на C# по этому возможно чего-то просто не могу увидеть. Рою интернет несколько дней, не могу найти информацию о том как авторизироваться через токен группы. Хотел попробовать без JSON, просто чтобы поиграться с методами в консоли или в WPF, а потом уже развернуть на серверах. Т.е. я просто не могу понять как именно авторизироваться. Поскольку нигде нет нормального примера на С#, а те что есть, реализуют авторизацию от имени пользователя, а не группы.

Пример моего быдлокода:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        var api = new VkApi();

        api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams() //метод авторизации
        {
            ApplicationId = 7120944, //id приложения. 
            AccessToken = "****",//ключ токен от группы

        });

        // Отправка сообщения себе
        api.Messages.Send(new VkNet.Model.RequestParams.MessagesSendParams
        {
            UserId= 8238539, //тут ид пользователя кому нужно отправить сообщение
            Message = "message" //само сообщение
        });

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Какую бибилиотеку используете?

Comment: Подключил библиотеку vknet.

Answer (score 0):

**Код является сугубо теоретическим и использовать такое в продакшене не рекомендую**
Достаём адресата из диалогов группы, потом указываем его в запросе на отправку сообщений

```
        var random = new Random();            
        var api = new VkApi();
        api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams {AccessToken = Token});

        var dialogs = api.Messages.GetConversations(new GetConversationsParams
        {
            Count = 5, Offset = 0
        });

        api.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams
        {
            RandomId = random.Next(),
            PeerId = dialogs.Items[0].Conversation.Peer.Id,
            Message = "It works"
        });
```

И естественно это не единственный способ сделать это. Подробнее можно почитать в официальной [документации](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send?params[random_id]=35467&params[user_ids]=8238539&params[message]=Test%20message&params[dont_parse_links]=0&params[disable_mentions]=0&params[v]=5.101).

Comment: Не вышло... вот такая ошибка:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Arg_ParamName_Name'

Comment: Напишите со своего аккаунта сообществу

Comment: строка с авторизацией помогла разобраться. спасибо! `api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams {AccessToken = Token});`

Comment: Всегда рад помочь)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала объявите экземпляр класса, в моем случае `VkApi Api = new VkApi();`

```
void authorize()
                    {
                        api.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams() { AccessToken = "token" }); //API key
                    }
```

Далее вызываете функцию, которая авторизует Вас, и после, запросите запросите LongPoll сервер, чтобы с него потом спрашивать нужные Вам данные.
Пример вырванного куска

```
var s = new LongPollServerResponse();
s = api.Groups.GetLongPollServer(id); //id группы
            while (true)
                {
                    var poll = api.Groups.GetBotsLongPollHistory(
                    new BotsLongPollHistoryParams()
                    { Server = s.Server, Ts = s.Ts, Key = s.Key, Wait = 25 });
                    if (poll?.Updates == null) continue;
                    foreach (var a in poll.Updates)
                    {
                        if (a.Type == GroupUpdateType.MessageNew)
                        {
                            userMessage = a.Message.Body;       //Сообщение
                            userID = a.Message.UserId;          //ID пользователя, отправившего сообщение
                            payload = a.Message.Payload;
                        }
                    }
               }
```

Для отправки сообщений использую

```
void SendMessage(string message, long? ID)
                {
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    api.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams
                    {
                        RandomId = rnd.Next(),
                        UserId = ID,
                        Message = message
                    });

                }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! То есть я сначала авторизируюсь, потом уже ввожу данные LongPoll сервера? Это все без json, по сути все это можно упростить через json запрос, верно?

Comment: Да, сначала нужно авторизироваться, потому что вк просто так Вам ничего не отдаст)

Все ответы от вк приходят в json, подключенная Вами библиотека сама все преобразует в человеческий формат данных

Comment: Просто везде видел как данные сериализуют в json, а потом десериализуют, говорят "это удобно", а почему это удобно непонятно =) Спасибо за ответы!